# CMake user built libraries; cannot specify link libraries for target

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker, cmake

I'm building a project in Cpp that will communicate with my Java apps via rabbitmq and post updates to twitter.  I'm using a few libraries from github

1. [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c)

   Rabbit installed to /usr/local/lib64
2. [jansson - json library](https://github.com/akheron/jansson/)

   I installed this a while back for another project, went to /usr/local/lib
3. [twitcurl - C lib for Twitter API](https://github.com/swatkat/twitcurl)

   Got installed to /usr/local/lib

If it matters, I'm using CLion as my IDE, which displays jansson and rabbit under auto-complete when defining includes - so that's picking the libs off my system somehow

```
e.g.
#include <jansson.h>
#include <amqp.h>
```

I link them using the target_link_libraries(name libs...) and I see output saying

```
build$ cmake ..

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "twitcurl" which is not built by
  this project.
```

I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64
```

I try to set the CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH to include usr/local/lib and lib64 but doesn't seem to have any effect.  Here's my CMakeLists.txt file

```
#
# This is a CMake makefile.  You can find the cmake utility and
# information about it at http://www.cmake.org
#

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(PROJECT_NAME twitterUpdater)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/usr/local/lib"
        "/usr/local/lib64")

project(${PROJECT_NAME})
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

IF (X11_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
    LINK_LIBRARIES(${X11_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF ( X11_FOUND )

IF (OpenCV_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})
ENDIF(OpenCV_FOUND)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${project_name} twitcurl jansson rabbitmq)
```

What's confusing me is another project I have uses jansson by simply adding it here `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${project_name} dlib jansson)`

What did I miss??  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake variables are case sensitive, thus the variable `${project_name}` results in an empty string. Use `${PROJECT_NAME}` instead, i.e.:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} twitcurl jansson rabbitmq)
```

Running CMake with the flag `--warn-uninitialized` helps you detect mistakes like this.